# emacsclient does not connect inside ubuntu container

Tags: emacs

I am trying to run `emacsclient` inside distrobox ubuntu container. If I run just `emacs`, it starts. But `emacsclient .` does not.

After starting `emacs --daemon`,
Output of `emacsclient --socket-name /run/user/1000/emacs/server .`

```
Waiting for Emacs...
*ERROR*: Could not open file: /dev/pts/5
```

Output of `sudo emacsclient --socket-name /run/user/1000/emacs/server .`

```
emacsclient: Invalid socket owner
emacsclient: error accessing socket "/run/user/1000/emacs/server"
```

Some information about systems

```
GNU Emacs: 27.1
distrobox: 1.7.1.0
ubuntu: 22.04
```